# How to beat Noel Kreiss?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

So I have reached the battle with Noel and I cannot beat him at all. I have 5 potions and 1 phoenix down and I have the 2 EP required for a Curaga.

My setup is Physical dmg, Magic dmg and a 'Defender' with the lightning physical attack.

What techniques am I missing which is causing me to run out of all my potions and my EP abilities whilst only managing to get him down to about 50% HP.

Does the block timing really make that much difference? Should you block each strike of a combo attack?

I'm feeling quite lost with this battle and frankly, it's putting me off wanting to play any more.

Comment: Could this be because I've not completed enough quests yet? I understand you don't level up, but gain stats through quests. Am I just too weak atm? 4k HP on my second day.

Comment: if you feel not strong enough just leave him and go to next town (i prefer yusnaan) and do sidequest there. And you can get pretty strong  suit from chocobogirl there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GameSpot has a video guide on this encounter.

Some actual stats on Noel can be found on the [Final Fantasy Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Noel_Kreiss_%28Boss%29).

> Noel has plenty of HP, and he can be difficult to defeat if Lightning's stats are low. When it comes to offense, Lightning should be equipped with schemata that possess Thunder-based attacks, such as Sparkstrike. Attack should also be equipped. Deprotect and Deshell can be used to increase the damage Lightning deals to Noel, as well as to nullify the buffs that the boss casts on himself. Careful timing is needed to guard against Meteor Javelin.

He is primarily vulnerable to Ice and Lightning. So any combination of these elements will help to stagger him. Once he is staggered, hit him with Physical attacks.

Be sure to guard against 'Meteor Javelin', as it will deal significant damage.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I watched the video. Your very first hit was 1254 HP. My first hit was about 275. I still got him down to 25% so I think I have the attack strategy down. Obviously, I missed something on how to level up Lightning. I'm confused by the whole schemata thing. I'm at the end of day two. I don't mind grinding, but from what I've read, you can't level up by grinding. What should I do?